# How to get unique Date in array.map loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date

So i want to set update date for every object in my array. In case, that `'update date'` is method that i'm using to order items in my list, i need to make `'update date'` unique value.

Map loop works too fast, so there can be a situation, when it will get same update Date. So i need to add something. I'm trying to add index, but after it happens i'm getting in firebase timestamp in not my timezone of my country. How to do it correctly?

```
newOrder.map(async (param, index) => {
      await db
        .collection(`dictionaries/ESTATE_PARAMS/${estateType}/${category.id}/params`)
        .doc(param)
        .update({
          updated: {
            at: new Date() + index,
            by: uid
          }
        })
    })
```

Comment: You could set a value now: `const now = Date.now();` before the map and then in the map do: `at: new Date(now+index)`

Comment: Supa dupa! Thanks allot!